# Generate random hexadecimal to change color in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page that has a div element with a colored background.

I want the color to change each time someone loads the page.

I found this snippet of code online which apparently generates a random hexadecimal number:

```
'#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
```

I'm new to JavaScript and so I'm trying to piece together how I implement this.

I assume that I assign a variable to the randomly generated hexadecimal:

```
bandColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
```

Now I'm not sure whether I use this variabile (bandColor) in my stylesheet or my html.

If it's the html, I'm guessing I do something like this in the JavaScript:

```
$("#band").html(bandColor);
```

And then in the html:

```
<div id="band">
```

Would appreciate anyone who can point out what I have right / wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure javascript solution can be:

`document.getElementById("band").style.background = "blue";`

And with random color:

`document.getElementById("band").style.background = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);`

Comment: This answer sometimes generates invalid 5-digit color strings.

Comment: I used it but always generates valid one, If something you know better, welcome for edit,

Answer (score 2):

Try the style attribute of the element, so:

```
$("#band").css("background-color", bandColour);
```

Side note: sometimes your code will generate a five-digit or fewer hex string, like `#9eb8d`. You can fix this by [left-padding with zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1267283/1757964):

```
bandColour = ("000000" + bandColour).slice(-6);
```

which you would put before the statement where you set the background color.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript in external or embed style-sheet for CSS.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#band{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #123456;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="band"><div>
<script>
var bandColour = document.getElementById('band');
bandColour.style.backgroundColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```